# not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql

`thumbnail` and `image` are BLOB field, `num1` and `num2` are Integer field, others are Str.

I want to insert binary data into MYSQL. But When this line called, error occured.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO image(num1, num2, filename, ext, thumbnail, image) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);" , (num1, num2, _name, _ext, _thumb, _image))
```

Error text: not all arguments converted during string formatting

How to fix it? Please teach me.

Comment: Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file

Answer (score 5):

If you are using MySQLdb, try:

```
cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO image
    (num1, num2, filename, ext, thumbnail, image) VALUES
    (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""" , (num1, num2, _name, _ext, _thumb, _image))
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm using MySQLdb. This way can prevent SQL injection?

Comment: @moruru: Yes, using parameters in the SQL and passing arguments to `cursor.execute` helps prevent SQL injection.

Comment: And what if _name has the value ''); DROP TABLE IMAGE;-- or something similar? Will that *still* prevent SQL injection? The INSERT will fail, but will the subsequent query run?

Comment: @Josh Smeaton: Since `filename` is some kind of text field, if  `_name` is the string `"); DROP TABLE IMAGE;"` then that is the string which will be inserted into the `filename` field. No SQL injection will occur.